# mysql crosstab query into php array - instead of three sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'd like  to select sum of three columns from three tables in mysql and then get it as php array.

Tables:

```
Amex:
incr_id,check_no, card_no, tip, total, date;
Mc:
incr_id,check_no, card_no, tip, total, date;
Visa
incr_id,check_no, card_no, tip, total,date ;
```

Pseudo code :

```
 $query = 
 select sum(tip) from Amex,
 select sum(tip) from Mc,
 select sum(tip) from Visa
 WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()

 mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

and then 'foreach' or 'while' to get three values into php array:

```
$ccpayments_tip['Amex']
$ccpayments_tip['Mc']      
$ccpayments_tip['Visa']
```

Is this possible or I will have to execute three select queries?
Thanks!

Comment: are there any other common fields you can group by? How can you identify between the Credit Card type, by the table it'd in? Adding the table structure would help

Comment: it's grouped by date (today, yesterda) and credit card type - so sum from mc from today (or yesterday) - isn't that enough?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a Union query to do all three at once, with a derived field to indicate which table the sums are coming from:

```
$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT 'Amex' AS source, SUM(tip) AS sum FROM Amex
UNION
SELECT 'MC' AS source, SUM(tip) AS sum FROM Mc
UNION
SELECT 'Visa' AS source, SUM(tip) AS sum FROM Visa

EOL;

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$ccpayments_tip = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $ccpayments_tip[$row['source']] = $row['sum'];
}
```

Of course, why do you have 3 seperate tables for this? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a single `creditcard` table with a `type` field to indicate if it's visa/amex/mc?

Comment: good point: i have four tables (cash, mc, visa, amex) where transactions from every day are stored -  to have just one table may be better. I did it because I expect to have many records accumulated over the years.

Comment: Bad idea to split by CC type. You'd probabyl find that the visa table becomes very large, Mc a bit smaller, and amex very small. Look into table partitioning (which mysql supports). It'd be better to partition on dates, so older transactions are kept separate from newer ones.

Comment: Yes - main purpose will be selecting transactions from all types from yesterday, week ago or month ago. I'll have to reconsider.
 your php loop returns empty Array.

Comment: Ah right. I missed a `{` in there (put a `;` instead), so the loop is actually an empty body. I'll mod the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) of the three queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Pseudo

```
SELECT A.Amex, M.MC, V.Visa 
FROM 
   (SELECT SUM(tip) AS Amex FROM Amex WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()) AS A,
   (SELECT SUM(tip) AS Mc FROM Mc WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()) AS M,
   (SELECT SUM(tip) AS Visa FROM Visa WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()) AS V
```

UPDATE: Pseudo Code as well

```
/*
'*CARD TYPES            *PREFIX           *WIDTH
'American Express       34, 37            15
'Diners Club            300 to 305, 36    14
'Carte Blanche          38                14
'Discover               6011              16
'EnRoute                2014, 2149        15
'JCB                    3                 16
'JCB                    2131, 1800        15
'Master Card            51 to 55          16
'Visa                   4                 13, 16
*/   

SELECT SUM(tip), CASE
    WHEN card_no >= 4 AND card_no <= 5 THEN 'visa'
    WHEN card_no >= 51 AND card_no <= 56 THEN 'mc'
    WHEN card_no >= 34 AND card_no <= 38 THEN 'amex'
    ELSE NULL
END AS credit_card_type
FROM Amex, Mc, Visa
WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN card_no >= 4 AND card_no <= 5 THEN 'visa'
    WHEN card_no >= 51 AND card_no <= 56 THEN 'mc'
    WHEN card_no >= 34 AND card_no <= 38 THEN 'amex'
    ELSE NULL
END AS credit_card_type
```

Haven't tested either query just a example to maybe think outside of the box

UPDATE from your comment:

If you're going to move to a transaction database and store the card_type you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(tip)
FROM transaction_tbl
WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY card_type
```

Comment: in this case credit card numbers are hidden(xxxxxxxxxxxxx4321) except last four digits. i will think about changing structure of database and put everything into one table with cc type column - what do you think?

Comment: I see no problem with implementing a transaction database that stores all the above info as well as a card_type. Just make sure to use indices. On a side note, not sure if you have every checked out PostgreSQL but I would recommend it.